# Testing if user hit enter(while still testing for good input)

Tags: c++, input

I have a loop that i want to exit upon the enter key hit at the first cin, but i'm having trouble getting the program to work correctly. Currently i have:

```
while(running) {
    cout << "enter word: ";
    getline(cin,starting);
    if(ladder.validWord(starting))
        running = false;
    else if(starting.empty())
        return 0;
    else
        cout << "invalid word...\n";
}
```

I need to extract good input, while still testing for the enter key hit. Currently this still exits the program, and gives me some weird jumble(at the end of the program) that seems to be cut from my directory on the command line,  such as:

```
g-dev@gdev-virtualBox:~/folder/ComputerProgramming/Wor$ dLadder
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getline IS your test.  getline only returns when someone hits enter.

```
 // extract to string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string getInput(std::string prompt){

    std::string name;

    std::cout << prompt;
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    if (name == "") 
        exit(1);

    return name;
}
main ()
{
    std::string name;
    while  (name != "poo"){

        name = getInput("enter someting good:\n");
    }

    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this? so this could be placed in a conditional statement? EDIT: alright, thanks for the correction on getline use. But this does not seem to help me, I still need a way to test and return when enter is hit while still grabbing input, i'm not quote following what you're getting at.

Comment: sure, getline could be part of a test.  I'll edit my example to include a test

Comment: Matrin, `cin >>` also blocks until enter is pressed, i get that part, but I dont know how to isolate the condition of only enter being pressed from normal input.

Comment: exactly. JUST enter, while any string is considered good input and will be tested, the way of exiting the program will be hitting the enter key when prompted to enter a string.

Comment: See my updated example - if ONLy enter is pressed, do one thing, other wise, do the other. since getline only returns on \n, if you test name, and it's null, only enter was pressed.

Comment: this is what I have currently, only "" being `.empty` instead.

Comment: So, if someone enters text, but the text fails your test, you want to prompt them for more text.  To do that. move your getline to a blocking function that contains getline, and when the function returns, if the text fails your test, call the function again, other wise, if enter alone was entered, exit, and if test passes, do what ypu originally set out to do with the test that passes your test. Do you want an example?

Comment: Ok, I added a while,loop, so until the input string equals "poo",  the app will loop forever, until: 1. you hit enter 2, you enter "poo". C++ is my worst language, but this is basic program flow, nothing C++ specific so you should understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will help you or not but you can at least use it as a possible solution to your problem. When I want my program to wait for the user to hit enter this is what I usually do:

```
cout << "Press <enter> to continue...";

// this ignore statement will wait until the user presses <enter>    
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

I hope it helps.